# Array initialization for non-copyable type

Tags: arrays, rust, initialization

I want to be able to do this:

```
let mut my_array: [MyType; 10] = [MyType::new(1, 2, 3, 4); 10];
```

when `MyType` isn't copyable, i.e. I want it to call the constructor for each element rather than calling it once and trying to copy. Is this possible?

Is it also possible to include the array index in the constructor call:

```
let mut my_array: [MyType; 10] = [MyType::new(_index, 2, 3, 4); 10];
```

so that my array is initialized with `MyType:new(1,2,3,4)`, `MyType:new(2,2,3,4)`, `MyType:new(3,2,3,4)`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`array-init`](https://docs.rs/array-init/) library provides a safe interface to do this:

```
let mut my_array: [MyType; 10] = array_init(|i| MyType::new(i, 2, 3, 4));
```